# usersendinput and userpostmessage hooking

Tags: windows-7, kernel, hook, wdk

I want to hook the usersendinput and userpostmessage hooking in windows 7.It didnt export by SSDT.So I am unable to accomplish this via SSDT hooking.I want to write my own api handler for these api .How can I accomplish this?SSDT shadow hooking is possible or any other way to hook this?

Comment: Do you mean NtUserSendInput?

Comment: ya NTusersendinput and NtuserPostMessage only

Comment: Thank you for teaching me how to accept answer.I have done it.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must get address of SSDT Shadow.
Next get all handles in the system and iterate over all handles to get PID of csrss.exe.
Attach to csrss.exe process, get system calls indexes (for example from this - [WIN32K.sys system call table](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/win32k_syscalls/) and replace original system functions with your functions.
I may post example, but I dont have Windows 7 machine to test.

Comment: I have refered this site to shadow SSDT hooking http://www.kernelmode.info/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1082 bt after try this i got BSOD error or i can able to register the service when i try to start service of i got an error system can't find the file specified

Comment: any other reference is there for ssdt shadow hooking